# Can I merge the commits in my branch to main without write access?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

[image]

I committed some changes to a branch under my name and created a pull request. Once the pull request is approved, my team wanted me to merge the commits into main but looks like I don't have access.

Can I merge the commits anyway? Sorry if this is too basic of a question, I'm a beginner with git.

Comment: In this case, it looks like you are not authorized, so apply to a project maintainer to give you more access, or to merge your requests for you. No way around it I'm afraid.

Comment: You can do anything you like *on your computer*, but if they want you to add commits to the repository *on GitHub*, you will need permissions. Remember that Git is a "D"-VCS: a Distributed Version Control System. Using `git clone`, *everyone gets a full copy of the repository*, locally, on their own laptop (or whatever computer they have).

Comment: The *Git* model is: everyone copies the whole thing to their own computer. Then they do *whatever they want* because that's *their* copy. Then they synchronize, or don't, whenever they like, however they like. The Git-*Hub* model is: there's a central repository on GitHub. Everyone copies to their laptop, but then sends results *to* the central repo, and sometimes does things *with* the central repo. The central repo, on GitHub, has the permissions.